# Vagrant to model network environment

Tags: vagrant

I'm wanting to use vagrant to model live network setup for debugging purposes.

More specifically I'm wanting a network that of VM's that resembles the following:

```
---> 10.1.1.58/30 eth0  router1 eth1 x.x.x.130 (private network)
  |                                              |
  | bridge                                       | bridge
  |                                              |
---> 10.1.1.62/30 eth0  router2 eth1 x.x.x.131 (private network)
```

My Vagrantfile currently contains:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"

  config.vm.define :router1 do |router1|
    router1.vm.hostname = "router1"
    router2.vm.network :public_network
    router1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "x.x.x.130"
  end

  config.vm.define :router2 do |router2|
    router2.vm.hostname = "router2"
    router2.vm.network :public_network
    router2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "x.x.x.131"
  end
end
```

However, vagrant up produces 2 VM's with 3 ethernet adapters each.  eth0 which is some sort of NAT'd network.  Eth1 which is bridged to the local network (which is what I want).  And eth2 which has the ip's set as I wish.

How do I remove the NAT'd eth0, and ensure that on the host vboxnet0 is not visible from the host.  Or vboxnet0 doesn't have an IP on the host so it's only a acting as a bridge between router1 & 2?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a typo in 1st block (router2 instead of router1).
Also, Vagrant/VBox defines a default NIC connected to NAT.

You can define explicitly which NIC you are referring to via the ":adapter" parameter

    `config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp", adapter: 1
or
    config.vm.network :public_network, auto_config: true, adapter: 1`

You can also use a different approach like here  (http://www.jedi.be/blog/2011/11/04/vagrant-virtualbox-hostonly-pxe-vlans/).